# Visiting my custom Facebook tab app doesnt work on mobile?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile

I've currently setup a custom tab app on my fanpage - visiting this is working perfectly fine from my browser.

However when visiting the same url from my mobile, I just get some red text on Facebook saying "The page was not found".

I've defined the following (noteworthy) settings for the app:

- Namespace (which gives me a canvas page)
- Canvas url
- Secure canvas url
- Page tab url
- Secure page tab url

I then also tried to fill out the "Mobile site url" with the same url as the canvas url - thinking this was the missing brick? But atleast not difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

because in your mobile browser it will redirect to the m.facebook.com and this functionality is not available for the app users.

Comment: So what youre saying is that custom apps doesnt work from Mobile?

Comment: And if so, isnt there any way to atleast do some better fallback not resulting in this "page was not found"

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this functionality exactly but you can work around Facebooks limitations by providing a canvas app url, and using that to redirect mobile users to a mobile version of your app, and desktop users to the page tab version of your app.

Detailed instructions here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15860533/121285