# Why Facebook Page Tab Applications don't display on the Actual Facebook Mobile App?

Tags: facebook

I noticed that a `Facebook Page App` does not show in the actual `Facebook mobile application` when viewing the same page.

Is there a work around or is it just not possible and why?

Comment: Page tab apps are not available for mobile yet. You can set up a mobile site URL in your app settings – but that will run outside of the context of a page, so you will not be able to easily like-gate the content for example.

Comment: This is a solution that might work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856438/mobile-users-unable-to-access-facebook-page-tab/15860533#15860533