# PHP Redirect if on mobile device | Facebook tab page

Tags: facebook

Looking for some help here:

we have a Facebook tab page, which does not work on mobile devices, so want a PHP redirect code that will redirect to a mobile version away form Facebook.

We added website URL to "Mobile web" on Facebook but can not get that to work, so would like a PHP code just to dump in.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to direct users to a Canvas App Page, which will automatically redirect mobile users to your mobile site url. You can then use javascript to redirect desktop users to your Page Tab.

Detailed instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15860533/121285