# How does facebook mobile web-url for tabs work?

Tags: facebook

I want to be able to share an url on my facebook-page that refers to a page-tab, and have that user redirected to an external site if they are on a mobile.

In the settings for a facebook-app there is a field called mobile web. The explanation says "The Url for your mobile web app that facebook will be dierected to  from facebook." Perfect this is what I want.

My app is in sandbox–mode I have added an extrenal url like this: https://myapp.herokuapp.com/

It's the same as the one I use for my page-tab.

I went to the tab on Facebook and copy+paste that url so and can post it as my page

The url looks like this (but with other numbers):
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Testelitest/12039123?id=12039123&sk=app_1029381092381

If I click the link on a computer, I come to the page-tab. If I click the link on a mobile device I come to the page that posted the url. I expect to come to the external site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to route users via a canvas app url. When you go to the canvas app url in a mobile browser you will be redirected to the mobile url that you specified. You can use javascript on the canvas app to redirect non mobile users to your page tab.

Detailed instructions are available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15860533/121285