# Facebook application mobile redirect doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I was created an Facebook game application 1 years ago.
Some days ago, the mobile redirect stop working.
When user check on mobile the canvas URL (https://apps.facebook.com/raffle_game) it shows "The page you requested was not found".

At Facebook developers I was setup the mobile URL.
I use this solution: [Mobile users unable to access Facebook page tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856438/mobile-users-unable-to-access-facebook-page-tab)

Please help!

Best regards,
Feco

Comment: Facebook has disabled this on a large scale, because they found apps using this to redirect users to malware sites. There is a current open bug report for this. But last time I checked they hadn’t come up with a solution yet, but only said they would get in touch once their engineering team had figured out a solution.

Comment: Thanks Bro, very usefull ;)