# Facebook Custom Tab Unavailable in Mobile

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I followed the instructions in this post: [Mobile users unable to access Facebook page tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856438/mobile-users-unable-to-access-facebook-page-tab/15860533#15860533) to try and get my Custom Page Tab to appear in mobile browsers, and mobile Facebook apps for Android and IPhone. However, it does not work.  I fear that all these posts are dated and no longer apply to Facebook API 2.7.

Currently the Page Tab application works fine in a PC browser, except there seems to be no way to make this Page Tab the default one. That would be ideal. More problematic though is that I can't get the tab to appear at all in mobile browser or mobile FB application.  Furthermore if I go to my redirect page: https://www.libertylive2016.com/facebook/Redirection.aspx?fb the redirect doesn't seem to work on m.facebook.com. The page comes back as unauthorized or unavailable.

Is there a 2016 way of solving this issue?  I have the beginnings of a slideshow at: https://www.libertylive2016.com/facebook/TabLibertyLive2016.aspx which I want to put on a custom tab that is accessible to all. The facebook page is http://www.facebook.com/libertylive2016. The custom tab is called "Liberty Live 2016"

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Page tab apps have never been available on mobile.

Comment: So what was that previous answer about? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856438/mobile-users-unable-to-access-facebook-page-tab/15860533#15860533

Comment: That was about setting up a system so that you can redirect mobile users somewhere else. But be warned, Facebook doesn't allow it any more to use canvas for the sole purpose of redirecting somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the answer is that it is impossible. Pretty pathetic indictment of Facebook's technology.