# Page Tabs on Mobile

Tags: facebook

I've seen this thread: [Mobile users unable to access Facebook page tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856438/mobile-users-unable-to-access-facebook-page-tab)

As well as the facebook developer's group question linked within which says that there are no plans for making page tabs available on mobile.

Is this for every app/iframe? I have a custom video player which allows users to click on it, a form of interactive video, is there a way to appeal for specific apps that are non-intrusive?

Comment: _“Is this for every app/iframe?”_ - specific to page tabs. Whether that even affects you is rather unclear at the moment, because what you described does rather not sound like a page tab app to begin with …?

Comment: What could I use instead? @CBroe
I used a custom tab to put my video player in an iframe, but the custom tab doesn't even show up on mobile.